# I want to refresh a page only when a new photo from the webcam has been uploaded

Tags: html, webcam

I have set up a webcam at work which uploads a photo and refreshes the page every 5 minutes. However when there is some activity it uploads a new pic every few seconds. How can I refresh the page everytime a new pic is uploaded?
Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

You must specify which technology you are using.Anyways if you used any modern technology then you can use timer which will refresh page after particular timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

This is not trivial. There are ways to do "long polling" with the server *pushing* data to a JavaScript running in the browser (the technology is named COMET) but that's a lot of work to set up. It will also require server side programming.

Is a frequent refresh every few seconds, or alternatively a JavaScript/Ajax based solution that makes a quick check every few seconds, totally out of the question?